# Graphic package

Tags: errors

Please help, i'm going crazy =)
I have new computer and I downloaded Latex and from the old computer I got my "script" in Latex. When I run it on new computer there are bunch of errors. The one I can not figure out is graphics package... I downloaded few graphics packeges with Latex Manager but still does not work...

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{pst-graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{pst-graphicx}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lhelp}
\usepackage{optparams}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

```
("C:\Users\Spela\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\longtable.st
y")

! LaTeX Error: File `pst-graphicx.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

Please please help...

Comment: [Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  As the error message indicates, LaTeX can't find `pst-graphicx.sty` which should be included in the `pst-graphicx` package.  Make sure you have that package installed and all other packages up to date.  Although I haven't used MikTeX in a long time, I'm sure there is a way to find which package contains a particular file.

Comment: I installed it with Latex Package Manager... so there should be everything I need, or not? Really don't know what to do...

Comment: Go into the MiKTeX package manager and (re)install the package. However, I believe that you do not really need that package. And that `\usepackage[pdftex]{pst-graphicx}` should be `graphicx`, not `pst-`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lhelp}
\usepackage{optparams}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```